# Why Does the Model not Improve in PyTorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, curve-fitting

I have a simple curve fitting problem in hand. I wrote some code in PyTorch as follows:

```
class MyDatasetV1(torch.utils.data.Dataset):

  def __init__(self, dataset):

    # Initialize a dataset

    assert isinstance(dataset, list), '"dataset" must be of "tuple" type'
    assert isinstance(dataset[0], torch.Tensor), '"x" must be of "torch.Tensor" type!'
    assert isinstance(dataset[1], torch.Tensor), '"y" must be of "torch.Tensor" type!'

    self.x = dataset[0]
    self.y = dataset[1]
    self.length = self.x.shape[0]

  def __len__(self):

    # Get the number of elements in entire dataset

    return self.length

  def __getitem__(self, index):

    return self.x[index], self.y[index]

class MyModelV2(torch.nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, input_size, output_size, hiddens, weights, biases, batchnorms, activations, dropouts):

    # Initialize a custom fully-connected model

    super(MyModelV2, self).__init__()

    assert len(hiddens) + 1 == len(weights), 'Number of hidden layers must match the number of "weights" units/tensors!'
    assert len(hiddens) + 1 == len(biases), 'Number of hidden layers must match the number of "bias" units/scalars!'
    assert len(hiddens) + 1 == len(batchnorms), 'Number of hidden layers must match the number of "batch normalization" units!'
    assert len(hiddens) + 1 == len(activations), 'Number of hidden layers must match the number of "activation" functions!'
    assert len(hiddens) + 1 == len(dropouts), 'Number of hidden layers must match the number of "dropout" units!'

    self.weights = weights
    self.biases = biases
    self.batchnorms = batchnorms
    self.activations = activations
    self.dropouts = dropouts
    self.layers_size = [input_size]
    self.layers_size.extend(hiddens)
    self.layers_size.append(output_size)
    self.layers = torch.nn.ModuleList()

  def build(self):

    # Build a model with given specifications

    for index in range(len(self.layers_size) - 1):

      layer = torch.nn.Linear(self.layers_size[index], self.layers_size[index + 1])

      if self.weights[index]:

        self.weights[index](layer.weight)

      if self.biases[index]:

        self.biases[index](layer.bias)

      self.layers.append(layer)

      if self.batchnorms[index]:

        self.layers.append(torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(self.layers_size[index + 1]))

      if self.dropouts[index]:

        self.layers.append(torch.nn.Dropout(self.dropouts[index]))

      self.layers.append(self.activations[index])

  def forward(self, x):

    # Forward pass for a given input

    for layer in self.layers:

      x = layer(x)

    return x

def set_weight(weights):

  return torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(weights)

def set_bias(biases):

  return torch.nn.init.zeros_(biases)

torch.manual_seed(7)

model = MyModelV2(1, 1, [64, 64], 3 * [set_weight], 3 * [set_bias], 3 * [False], 3 * [torch.nn.ReLU()], 3 * [False])
model.build()

criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())

x = torch.linspace(-10, 10, 1000 * 1).reshape((1000, 1))
y = 0.1 * x * torch.cos(x) + 0.05 * torch.normal(1, 2, size=(1000, 1))

ds = MyDatasetV1([x, y])
ds_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(ds, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

def get_training_loss(model, training_loader, criterion, optimizer):

  # Training loop for a given model

  model.train()
  training_loss = 0.0

  for x_train, y_train in training_loader:

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    y_hat_train = model(x_train)
    train_loss = criterion(y_hat_train, y_train)
    train_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    training_loss += train_loss.item()

  # Calculate the average training loss

  training_loss /= len(training_loader)

  return training_loss

EPOCHS = 100

for epoch in range(1, EPOCHS + 1):

  tr = get_training_loss(model, ds_loader, criterion, optimizer)

  print(f'Epoch number: {epoch} - Training error/loss: {tr:.6e}')

def predictor(model, x):

  # Predict after training for a given model

  model.eval()

  with torch.no_grad():

    x = model(x)

  return x

y_hat = predictor(model, x)

plt.figure(dpi=120)
plt.plot(x.numpy(), y.numpy(), 'ro', markersize=1.5, label='(x, y)')
plt.plot(x.numpy(), y_hat.numpy(), 'bo', markersize=1.5, label='(x, $\hat{y}$)')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Even though I tried different models, i.e., 32, 32 or 64, 32, 16 neurons at hidden layers, etc., I ended up having a zero prediction from all as shown in the figure below.

[image: Dataset and predictions]

I reviewed my model many times, but I could not figure out the issue here. What is wrong with it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whom this post and reply might be useful,

If the model is examined carefully, the `ReLU` activation function at the end before the output neurons is what causes the problem. Since the dataset consists of positive and negative values, using `ReLU` activation function just before the output neurons prevents the model from learning the negative values of `y` in the dataset as seen in the plot above.

Comment: Well done to find this bug. Your answer does show why this kind of question gets low interest. At the very least the expert helping has to carefully read *all* the code, they probably have to get more involved and run it. I've answered a few similar and they have been very time consuming